# Create SQS queue for consuming events with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a spring boot application which needs to consume different types of events. The events will be published by another service to an SQS queue.

My question is, do I have to create one SQS queue where all the events will be published/consumed or do I have to create one SQS queue for each and every event that will be published/consumed?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a queue for each message, but I don't recommend it ass you'll have to add a listener to each queue every time you add a new message.

First thing that you can do is to create a message structure that holds the topic inside it. Once your SQS handler receives a message, it will check the topic and route it to the right handler or handlers.
I still don't like this option because this means what you are implementing is a message broker and I don't think that's what you are aiming for.

The best solution would be to use SNS and publish each message to a different topic. Then configure SNS to route the message to that SQS and let your spring SQS message handler to get the right handler by the topic.
While this solution is similar to the previous one, the use of SNS here gives you the ability to publish a message to more than one queue (client) and handles, and you get the topic outside the message which is where it should be.